# XAML to Rtf conversion in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

.NET 4, WPF MVVM here. I'm trying to use this [converter](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e)
to convert from Xaml back to Rtf to appear in a `RichTextBox`

Here is an example of a Xaml string parameter being passed into my method:

```
<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Section TextAlignment="left" FontWeight="normal" FontStyle="normal" FontSize="12px" FontFamily="segoe ui" Foreground="#000000"><Paragraph FontSize="14px" FontFamily="arial" Margin="0"><Span><Run>Test body.</Run></Span></Paragraph><List MarkerStyle="Disc" Margin="0" Padding="0"><ListItem><Paragraph FontSize="14px" FontFamily="arial" Margin="0"><Span><Run>Bullet 1</Run></Span></Paragraph></ListItem><ListItem><Paragraph FontSize="14px" FontFamily="arial" Margin="0"><Span><Run>Bullet 2</Run></Span></Paragraph></ListItem></List><Paragraph FontSize="14px" FontFamily="arial" Margin="0"><Span><Run>Back to text.</Run></Span></Paragraph></Section></FlowDocument>
```

Here is my XamlToRtf method from my viewModel:

```
private string ConvertXamlToRtf(string richTextBoxText)
{
    var richTextBox = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBoxText))
    {
        return "";
    }

    var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

    using (var xamlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var xamlStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(xamlMemoryStream))
        {
            xamlStreamWriter.Write(richTextBoxText);
            xamlStreamWriter.Flush();
            xamlMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            textRange.Load(xamlMemoryStream, DataFormats.Xaml);
        }
    }

    using (var rtfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd); 
        textRange.Save(rtfMemoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        rtfMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var rtfStreamReader = new StreamReader(rtfMemoryStream))
        {
            return rtfStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

The Xaml is passed into the text range however at the line `textRange.Load(xamlMemoryStream, DataFormats.Xaml);` the text is stripped from the textRange and I end up with an empty Rtf shell with the `FlowDocument` Xaml tags still included like this:

```
<FlowDocument>{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs18\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f2 \li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
}}</FlowDocument>
```

Is `DataFormats.Xaml` failing to recognise some of my Xaml code, not sure why it's stripping all the text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextRange` apparently cannot be a `FlowDocument` itself, only a `Section`, for example.

This means, you should not wrap your XAML input in `<FlowDocument>`, but simply use `<Section>` instead.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou! hard-coded <Section> as a wrapper & text is saved :)